# Firebase POJO not working, not recognizing class that I am try to cast to

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pojo

When I run the code below, I get the following error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class java.util.HashMap has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead.

```
seniorRef.orderByChild("seniorID").equalTo(caretaker.getSeniorID())
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Log.d("senior", data.toString());
                Senior senior = data.getValue(Senior.class);
                seniorBox.setText(senior.getFirstName() + " " + senior.getLastName());
                caretasks(senior);
            }
        }
```

What's weird is that this code was working perfectly for a very long time and I made minor changes to the Senior class (below) for stuff that I am currently working on. It was working when I made some progress last night but now it refuses to convert it from a HashMap to Senior. If I try casting it as (Senior) data.getValue(), it throws a type conversion error. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
public class Senior implements Serializable {

private String seniorID;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String address;
private HashMap<String, HashMap> activities;

public Senior (){}

...

}
```

Edit: It's also worth mentioning that I have another class that makes the exact same query on the same object, which works just fine.

Comment: Is it possible that you have data in the database currently that doesn't match with changes you recently made to Senior.class?

Comment: @MacLeanSochor I got the `HashMap<String, HashMap> activities` parameter to write to the db yesterday, I just tried deleting that particular node from the db and it works, so the error is definitely there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your `HashMap` does not have `generic type parameters`. The `<String, Object>` are missing. So in order to solve this, you need to change this line:

```
private HashMap<String, HashMap> activities;
```

with this line:

```
private Map<String, Map<String, Object>> activities;
```

And now you can get the data accordingly.

Hope it helps.